# Using Python and Numpy to blend 2 images into 1

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I need to take 2 numpy.ndarrays as an arguments and iterate through each of them pixel by pixel, adding the 2 values and dividing by 2.

Essentially creating a blended image of the two and returning it as a numpy.ndarray

This is what i've come up with, but could really use some advice.

```
    def blendImages(image1, image2):            
        it1 = np.nditer(image1)
        it2 = np.nditer(image2)            
        for (x) in it1:
            for (y) in it2:
                newImage = (x + y) / 2
        return newImage
```

Comment: Since you included the OpenCV tag, you can use `dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)`

Comment: The thing to remember about numpy is that it does the iteration for you (and much faster than native Python).

Comment: Thank you Miki, that worked beautifully! I'm still wrapping my head around these functions, thanks jon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use OpenCV function [addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) like:

```
 cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)`
```

Comment: How do i do add weighted for more than 2 images?@Miki

Comment: @ryan for more than 2 images see the other answer

Comment: @Ryan, did you figure this out?  I get a white screen when I do `blendof8 = weight * images[0] + weight * images[1] +...`

Answer (score 6):

As long as the arrays are the same size:

```
newImage = 0.5 * image1 + 0.5 * image2
```

Comment: They are the same size, I should have mentioned that. Thank you ebo, I will give this a try.

Comment: Hard-coding the values (`0.5`) as you've done probably runs faster, but in general this could be done for any number of images as `def blendImages(*images): return np.mean(images, axis=0)`

Comment: Thank you guys, but I could not get that line of code to work correctly; the dst = cv2.addWeighted(image1,0.5,image2,0.5,0)  line did work however.

Comment: the result image is going full of white color why did this happen?

Comment: @askewchan, this returned a screen of all white pixels for me